# Manage WSDL soap operations with WSO2 API manager

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, wso2

I would like to know how can I manage SOAP wsdl operations with WSO2 api manager. Imagine that I want to expose only three of ten operations of my WSDL. There is only one endpoint in this wsdl. ¿Which is the best way to do that? I found this blog post helpful

http://charithaka.blogspot.com.es/2012/07/consuming-soap-service-using-wso2-api.html
but it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

thanks

cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the available operations to user, you can edit the wsdl, and provide that, when you publish the wsdl. So, users will see only available operations. If user send requests to other operations you can filter/drop them within sequence, by adding a custom extension sequence with your logic to the API.

Comment: I don't want to publish another wsdl, with the current wsdl I want to filter operations. What is a custom extension sequence?? thx

Comment: You can define mediation logic (ie: in your case filtering logic) in a sequence and can attach that to an API. Here is the guide http://docs.wso2.org/display/AM140/Adding+a+Mediation+Extension

Comment: This extension implies developing code to filter if an WSDL operation is enabled for certain partner/developer/user right? I don't understand why not, this feature is out of the box...

Comment: "I don't understand why not, this feature is out of the box." Not clear..what do you mean?